# some details in the content of Boundary Register

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

In a request pagination system which applies multilevel page table, what's the value of Boundary Register? max virtual address or max virtual page number?

Answer (score 0):

Number of entries in page table:
= (virtual address space size) / (page size)
= Number of pages

Virtual address space size:
= 2n B

Size of page table:
<>= (number of entries in page table)*(size of PTE)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).